# Why am I not getting the desired output?

Tags: c, string

The problem is to write the asked fibonacci word. For example if input is 0, then f(0) = a, if 1, f(1) = b and similarly f(2) = ba, f(3) = bab, f(4) = babba and so on. I wrote the following code to find the output on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Terminal. I am getting the right output for n=0,1,2,3. But for n=4 I am getting babb instead of babba. I have tried debugging also but could not find where the code is going wrong. Kindly help me in finding the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void fibonacci(int n);
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter the fibonacci nword number you want to see:(f(x), f(0) is the starting element.):\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Required Word is:\n");
    fibonacci(x);
    return 0;
}

void fibonacci(int n)
{
    int i,j=0;
    char *p,*q,*r;
    if(n==0)
    {
        printf("a\n");
    }
    else if(n==1)
    {
        printf("b\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        char str1[100] = "a";
        char str2[100] = "b";

    char str3[100];
        p = str1;
        q = str2;
        r = str3;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            *r = *q;
            strcat(str2,str1);
            *p = *r;
        }
        printf("%s\n",str2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The assignments `*r = *q;` and `*p = *r;` copy one single letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First answering the main question, as of "Why I'm not getting the desired output":

Because you don't know what you're doing.

You are declaring 3 char[] variables statically, assigning them to pointers of type char*, and not even using them correctly.

Let's annalyze a part of your code:

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    *r = *q;
    strcat(str2,str1);
    *p = *r;
}
```

### What you're doing is basically:

- assign str3[0] = 'b' (in *r = *q)
- copy the contents of str1 into str2, so, "ba" in the first run
- assign str1[0] = 'b' (in *p = *r)
- And then, repeatedly concatenate "b" into str2, because both str1 will only contain a single "b" for now on.

Doing that, for anything above 4, you'll only get "babbbbbbbbbb"...

My advice: If you're going to statically declare some variables, stop using pointers to access them. Try accessing the str1/str2 as vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is obfuscated.  I modified it so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char*fib(int n)
{
  if (0==n)
    return "a";
  else if (1==n)
    return "b";
  else
  {
    char static out[2000]={'b', 'a'};
    int idx=2, prev=1, tmp;
    n-=2;
    while(n--)
    {
      /* invariant: all values start at the beginning of `out`.
         idx: keep the length of the current object
         prev: keep the size of previous object
       */
      memcpy(out+idx, out, prev);
      tmp=prev;
      prev=idx;
      idx+=tmp;
    }
    return out;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  printf("Enter the fibonacci nword number you want to see:"
         "(f(x), f(0) is the starting element.):\n");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  printf("Required Word is:\n");
  printf("~~%s\n", fib(x));
  return 0;
}
```